# Using the Tensor Product Construction to Show Linear Independence of the Standard Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For simplicity's sake, let's assume $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ with standard basis $e_1, e_2$. I construct the tensor product $V \otimes V$ as the quotient of the the free vector space $F(V \times V)$ by the ideal generated by
$$
(a+b) \otimes c - a \otimes c - b \otimes c \\
a \otimes (b + c) - a \otimes b - a \otimes c \\
ra \otimes b - a \otimes rb 
$$
where $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

It is known that $B = \{ e_i \otimes e_j\}$ is a basis for $V \otimes V$.

How can one prove the linear independence of $B$ directly from the above construction (*i.e.* without using universal properties or dual spaces)?